Internal server error in Elasticbeanstalk after deployed my Django webapplication
This is the log data from Elastic beanstalk after deployed my Django web application
here are ImportErrors indicating that libGL.so.1 cannot be found, which is causing issues when importing cv2 in your Django views.
How to resolve this error ?
/var/log/web.stdout.log
----------------------------------------
Apr 19 15:05:21 ip-172-31-85-0 web: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
Apr 19 15:05:21 ip-172-31-85-0 web: File "/var/app/current/Cloud/urls.py", line 22, in <module>
Apr 19 15:05:21 ip-172-31-85-0 web: path('', include('CloudApp.urls')),
Apr 19 15:05:21 ip-172-31-85-0 web: File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/django/urls/conf.py", line 34, in include
Apr 19 15:05:21 ip-172-31-85-0 web: urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
Apr 19 15:05:21 ip-172-31-85-0 web: File "/usr/lib64/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
Apr 19 15:05:21 ip-172-31-85-0 web: return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
Apr 19 15:05:21 ip-172-31-85-0 web: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
Apr 19 15:05:21 ip-172-31-85-0 web: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
Apr 19 15:05:21 ip-172-31-85-0 web: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
Apr 19 15:05:21 ip-172-31-85-0 web: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
Apr 19 15:05:21 ip-172-31-85-0 web: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 843, in exec_module
Apr 19 15:05:21 ip-172-31-85-0 web: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
Apr 19 15:05:21 ip-172-31-85-0 web: File "/var/app/current/CloudApp/urls.py", line 3, in <module>
Apr 19 15:05:21 ip-172-31-85-0 web: from . import views
Apr 19 15:05:21 ip-172-31-85-0 web: File "/var/app/current/CloudApp/views.py", line 9, in <module>
Apr 19 15:05:21 ip-172-31-85-0 web: import cv2
Apr 19 15:05:21 ip-172-31-85-0 web: ImportError: libGL.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Apr 19 15:05:27 ip-172-31-85-0 web: Internal Server Error: /
Apr 19 15:05:27 ip-172-31-85-0 web: Traceback (most recent call last):
Apr 19 15:05:27 ip-172-31-85-0 web: File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
Apr 19 15:05:27 ip-172-31-85-0 web: response = get_response(request)
Apr 19 15:05:27 ip-172-31-85-0 web: File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 111, in _get_response
Apr 19 15:05:27 ip-172-31-85-0 web: resolver_match = resolver.resolve(request.path_info)
Apr 19 15:05:27 ip-172-31-85-0 web: File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 491, in resolve
Apr 19 15:05:27 ip-172-31-85-0 web: for pattern in self.url_patterns:
"/var/app/current/CloudApp/views.py", line 9, in <module>
Apr 19 15:05:27 ip-172-31-85-0 web: from . import views
Apr 19 15:05:27 ip-172-31-85-0 web: File "/var/app/current/CloudApp/views.py", line 9, in <module>
Apr 19 15:05:27 ip-172-31-85-0 web: import cv2
Apr 19 15:05:27 ip-172-31-85-0 web: ImportError: libGL.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory.```

